# How to create and modify custom document properties for office files

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office, office-addins

I was following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-create-and-modify-custom-document-properties?view=vs-2019) article, but Office.DocumentProperties throw error that Office does not have DocumentProperties defined.

```
private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties properties;

        var activeDocument = Globals.ThisDocument.Application.ActiveDocument;

        properties = (Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties)activeDocument.CustomDocumentProperties;

        MessageBox.Show(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(properties));
    }
```

Comment: Could you please use the [edit] link below the question to share the code you've tried in as a [mcve]? You might also want to read the site guidelines for asking effective questions in the [help]. Tagging the question with the programming language you're using would also be a good idea.

Comment: Your code works for me. Could you please also include the line that causing the error and the error message? And please check the project REFERENCES just to be sure there's a reference to the `Office` PIA.

Answer (score 1):

The [How to: Read from and write to document properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-read-from-and-write-to-document-properties?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019) article explains how to read from and write to Document Properties. The following code works like a charm on my PC:

```
Word.Document doc = WordApp.ActiveDocument as Word.Document; 
 Office.DocumentProperties properties = doc.CustomDocumentProperties as Office.DocumentProperties; 
 for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++) 
 { 
     Office.DocumentProperty property = properties[i]; 
     if(property!=null) 
     { 
         System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(property.Name); 
         Marshal.ReleaseComObject(property); 
     } 
 } 
 if (properties != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(properties); 
 if (doc != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
```

Sometimes, you need to use a late-binding technology to avoid exceptions:

```
dynamic properties = doc.CustomDocumentProperties;
```

Comment: I could not find DocumentProperties under Office class.

Which library reference are you using for this ?